# AutoMapper IDataReader Mapping default value to entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, automapper, mapper

im using AutoMapper for map entity and DataSet

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Home>():
```

and i have a property  call MobileNumber in Home entity and want to map static value for this property in entity so how can i add static value when entity is mapping with DataSet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i could find the way

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Booking>().ForMember(d => d.Days, opt => opt.UseValue(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a constant value for your MobileNumber property like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Home>().ForMember(dest => dest.MobileNumber,
                                                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => "MyConstantValue"));
```